# In Excel VBA, how do I refer to a named column that contains a single quote

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am investigating a bug in an Excel spreadsheet where the following formula is inserted into every cell in a column.

```
=AGGREGATE( 3, 5, InputData[@[Foo]:[Bar]]) > 0
```

The VBA is as follows:

```
Let AddColumn.DataBodyRange.formula = "=AGGREGATE( 3, 5, [@[Foo]:[Bar]]) > 0"
```

this will evaluate to `FALSE` if all of the cells on the current row between columns `Foo` and `Bar` are empty, otherwise it evaluates to `TRUE`

The problem I'm seeing is that the names `Foo` and `Bar` are variable and not under my control and the formula fails with Run-time error 1004 if a name contains a single quote:

```
Let AddColumn.DataBodyRange.formula = "=AGGREGATE( 3, 5, [@[Foo's name]:[Bar]]) > 0"
```

Is there a way I can escape the name in such a way that single quotes won't create the run-time error? Adding double quotes around the name gives me the same error.

Are there likely to be further problems if the names contain other characters that have special meaning in Excel?

I could also refer to the columns by address instead of name. Would that work with the current row '@' notation?

Excel version:14.0.7188.5002

Comment: Prefix any special characters in the column name with an apostrophe. That would include the characters: `'#@[]` as far as I remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers and comments put me on the right track:

```
Function escapedColumnName(columnName As String) As String
    columnName = Replace(columnName, "'", "''")
    columnName = Replace(columnName, "#", "'#")
    columnName = Replace(columnName, "[", "'[")
    columnName = Replace(columnName, "]", "']")

    escapedColumnName = columnName
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I hear you when you say the naming convention is "not under my control".  This really puts you in a bind when anything can be pumped into your code.

Sadly, the only solution is to scrub the input when they finally hand it over to you.  This involves you having to make your own vba function that takes in a string and returns a string that has special characters removed (or replaced with something else).

In your case, you are going to have to scrub the data in possibly two places.

First, you will need to change all the column names so they don't have special characters in them.  You'll need to access each name and send it through the 'scrub' function and then replace the name with the scrubbed name.

Second, when someone inputs a column name for your `AGGREGATE`, you'll need to capture that input into a string variable and then pass that through the 'scrub' function.  Then you'll need to validate that the input they gave you matches up with a valid column name.  If it's not valid, send them an error message asking them to enter a valid name or to cancel out.

After you have valid values for foo and bar, you can add them to your `AGGREGATE` function and let it execute.

If you can't scrub/change your column names, then you'll have to make a list of scrubbed column names and associate them with the column address.  Then when you get your input, scrub it, and then match to the list to grab the correct address.  Then you can use hard addresses instead of variable naming schemes.

It's a lot of work.  But it's necessary when you have naming conventions that are not under your control.